# transparent png image loses quality when including in TImageList

Tags: c++, png, vlc, c++builder-10.3-rio, timagelist

I need to use `png` images with transparent background in `TMainMenu` (via `TAction`) (C++).
But when including the images in the component, they lose quality, leaving some figures with a checkered appearance.
The images have a size of 21px and the component is configured with 21px as well. I've tried to include larger images (48px) but it has the same problem.
Would there be any way to resolve this?

Thank you in advance for your attention.

Comment: Adding a pair of tags (c++builder, vcl) you'll increase the chances to find someone who can answer. I'm still using BCB5, there `TImageList` doesn't support the alpha channel but just a single transparent color, so I have to create bitmaps blending pngs with a background color (I use imagemagick to automate this)

Comment: Also vital with C++ Builder that you state which IDE version you are using (lots of changes with images over recent versions) and also if it is a VCL or FMX project

Comment: beware glyphs uses transparent color at specific location (one of the corners) just like `*.ico` file format while other image fileformats either state such color in header or use alpha channel so you just might copy your transparent color to the correct pixel at load time to remedy this ...